# IOS Distribution release ipa different to debug version

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6, ios7

I just started IOS development this year and everything has been great until i tried to sumbit my app
to the store when I have completed.

The IPA file generated from the Archive (then exported as a ad-hoc ipa file) is different to the debug version. I found out this because while trying to
test the final IPA generated. When i try to load it up on the physical phone and install the final IPA using itunes and i can see the icon is different
compared to the latest version.

I did a product clean and it is still the same result. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?
By the way, i have the provisiong profiles setup correctly I believe.

Just want to clarify,
The final IPA is different to the version when I debug (From XCode just by running the play button)

Also,
Can someone let me know the proper way of testing the final IPA before submission to apps store?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Are you using Images.xcassets to add assets?

Comment: Nope. Sitll using the old way

Comment: what is your icon image name?

Comment: When i debug using the play button, everything works fine. I can see the new icon.

Comment: Did you uninstall your app and clean build?

Comment: Can't remember the full name. Dont have the code with me.
Something like iconBlaBlaBla.png

Comment: @DevojyotiAich ,Yes? I tried deleting from itunes but icon is different.

Comment: ok. did you add 2x image for that?

Comment: Are you using same device for debuging and testing adhoc build? And please check all app icons are correct(image, dimension) from project>Target>general.

Comment: @RajSubbiah, Yes, i added image for all the icons shown on the General setting page.

Comment: Change your ipa file extension to .zip. Extract it and right click on app file and select "show package content". And check all image resources are correct (latest) or not.

Comment: did u follow the apple recommended size and name for app icon? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1

Comment: @RajSubbiah, I am sure I followed the dimension. Will double check the name but I don't understand why it works in debug mode?

Comment: Did you get any warning while compiling the project using ad-hoc distribution profile?

Comment: @RajSubbiah, I read the link, the app name only need to be followed for IOS 3.1.1 or earlier

Comment: @RajSubbiah, I am using Xcode 5 and I don't have ad-hoc distribution profile but we have distribution profile. I believe there are the same? and no warnings.

Comment: Add the icon file name in Info.plist using CFBundleIcons key

Comment: @RajSubbiah, May i know how do you test your final IPA before submission?

Comment: You cannot instal distribution ipa, but you can install the Ad Hoc Distribution ipa and that should function exactly the same as the distribution one.

Comment: @SuleaCosmin to test for the ad hoc IPA, I need to manually change the provision profile to developer, right?

Comment: check this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Comment: @overule try deleting the old icon file from your project bundle. Also delete the app from the device and reinstall it.